# Dynamically replace a tag in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to generate the ID tag of a DIV dynamically in my MVC 4 view:

```
 <div id="newBox{0}"></div>
```

and replace the {0} with @Model.MyTag

What is the best practice for that?

Comment: Would `<div id="newBox@Model.MyTag"></div>` work?

Comment: @Musa no, Razor parses that as being one whole string literal.

Comment: dbaseman is right. It becomes part of the string in the quotes. So, it does not work

Comment: You just need to use the right brackets (see my answer below)

Answer (score 4):

```
<div id="newBox@(Model.MyTag)"></div>
```

or

```
<div id="newBox@{Write(Model.MyTag);}"></div>
```

Both do HTML encoding (special chars safe).